# Should I ask for a payment for the outline of a course I am writing?

Tags: payment-terms, payments, writing

I am currently working as a technical freelance writer for a client. He has asked me to write 10 lengthy articles (~2000 Words each) about a technical topic in a "tutorial" fashion. We agreed on a fixed rate of $0.2 per word.

Before I started working on the 10 articles, I outlined the articles in a hierarchy of Article-Sections-Subsections-Brief Description in a document. After I was done, the whole outline document was 600 words.

So my question is, should I ask my client for a payment for that outline? (Given that I spent around 3 hours preparing it).

Answer (score 1):

It probably won't hurt to *ask* for payment, but if it's not something they agreed to in advance, don't be surprised if they decline.

You would probably be better off using your document as a "wireframe" for the series of articles, and incorporate as much (or all) of it that you can into the finished product.  You will recover your investment that way.

Answer (score 1):

your rate should include a 'cost of sales'.

I.e. when I make a quote for a customer, that usually costs me a few hours as well. I can't charge for that, but that cost is included in the total project cost. Would you consider this outline as part of a pre sales process or is it part of the project?

Unless you included the outline in the list of stuff the client would have to pay for, such as the articles, then it may be difficult to ask money for it. On the other hand if it is unclear, it is writing too, so why shouldn't it be invoiced?